# saving an event evolution in loops

Tags: matlab, loops, switch-statement

I am doing a simple simulation in matlab.

I have three stages a robot can be in. They are `Search`,`Assess` or `Recruit`. If the robot is in any of these stages there are certain actions to be performed. If the robot finished `Search`, it should go to `Assess`. If it finished `Assess`, then it should go to `Recruit`. When the robot reached the stage `Recruit`, the initial population of robots should reduced by 1. I am saving the `current_time` and the decrease from `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial`. I am finding some problem to break from while loop and saving `current_time` and `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial`. Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

```
for_distribution =  @(mean_time) log(1/(1-rand))/mean_time;
number_of_robots_in_nest_initial = 20
current_time = 0;
counter = 1;
state ='search';
mean_search_duration = 1998.849773195878;          
mean_assessment_duration = [93.63,99.050]; 
mean_recruitment_duration = 136.756;       
mean_threshold_time_to_pick_nest = [1309.01,1905.4];
while true
  switch state
      case 'search'
          t = for_distribution(mean_search_duration);
          current_time(counter+1) = current_time(counter) + t; %#ok<SAGROW>
          state = 'assessing';
      case 'assessing'
          t = for_distribution(mean_assessment_duration(1));
          current_time(counter+1) = current_time(counter) + t; %#ok<SAGROW>
          if current_time > mean_time_to_pick_nest(1)
              state = 'recruiting';
          else
              state = 'search';
          end
      case 'recruiting'
          t = for_distribution(mean_recruitment_duration);
          current_time(counter+1) = current_time(counter) + t; %#ok<SAGROW>
          number_of_robots_in_nest_initial(current_time(counter+1)) = number_of_robots_in_nest_initial(current_time(counter)) - 1;
          if number_of_robots_in_nest_initial(current_time) == 0
            break
        end
    end
    counter = counter+1;
end
```

Comment: Are `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial` and `Current_time` arrays? I feel like in the if condition you test if every value of `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial` is 0, but only the last one should be 0 right? I feel like  `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial(end) == 0` should do the trick

Comment: ALSO if you have a condition ending the loop you could use it instead of the `while true` and the if-condition: `while  number_of_robots_in_nest_initial(end) > 0` then you just have to take care of the fact that your `counter` would be 1 higher as the last `counter = counter+1;` would take place

Comment: `number_of_robots_in_nest_initial` and `Current_time` are not arrays.